# "unknown status code: 17042 Invalid format" error when using verification code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Problem: I am getting the following error when entering the phone number to receive a verification code: `Error FirebaseAuth [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17042 Invalid format`. I entered the number as so `+1xxxxxxxxxx`.

What I would like to be able to do ultimately is receive the verification code and verify to allow the user to get back in the game.

The code below is what I am using to send the sms verification code and to verify:

```
 void SMSVerification(string phone, bool consent_sent)
{
    if (consent_sent == true)
    {
        ///Application.OpenURL("sms:" + sms);

        var phoneAuthProvider = Firebase.Auth.PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(auth);
        phoneAuthProvider.VerifyPhoneNumber(phone, phoneAuthTimeoutMs, null,
        verificationCompleted: (cred) =>
        {
            if (signInAndFetchProfile)
            {
                auth.SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredentialAsync(cred).ContinueWith(HandleSignInWithSignInResult);
                Debug.Log("SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredentialAsync");
            }
            else
            {
                auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(cred).ContinueWith(HandleSignInWithUser);
                Debug.Log("SignInWithCredentialAsync");
            }
        },
        verificationFailed: (error) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Verification Failed");
        },
        codeSent: (id, token) =>
        {
            phoneAuthVerificationId = id;
            Debug.Log("Codesent successful");
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeOut: (id) =>
        {
            Debug.Log("CodeTiemOut");
        });
    }
}

public void VerifyReceivedPhoneCode()
    {
        var phoneAuthProvider = Firebase.Auth.PhoneAuthProvider.GetInstance(auth);
        // receivedCode should have been input by the user.

        //string code = verificationcodeInputField.text.ToString();
        string code = "Place Holder";
        Debug.Log("The Code for verification is" + code);
        var cred = phoneAuthProvider.GetCredential(phoneAuthVerificationId, code);
        if (signInAndFetchProfile)
        {
            auth.SignInAndRetrieveDataWithCredentialAsync(cred).ContinueWith(
            HandleSignInWithSignInResult);
        }
        else
        {
            auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(cred).ContinueWith(HandleSignInWithUser);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please remember to make your question title a summary of your problem, rather than a series of tags. I've edited it for you.

Comment: I checked the docs, are you using the format `+1 650-555-3434` or are you using `+1650-555-3434` it seems it's rather specific. (Note: these are not real phone numbers and are from google's example.

Comment: @DekuDesu: Can you please send me where in the docs it says that?

Comment: This is for andriod, but I assume the API is very similar, it's [here under `Test With Fictional Phone Numbers`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#test-with-fictional-phone-numbers) it mentions that there is a length and format requirement and they provide an example that is different from what you stated using.

Comment: @DekuDesu: Thank you. I will try to format the number

Comment: @DekuDesu: Thank you. Your suggestion work. I had to other issues after that but was able to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#test-with-fictional-phone-numbers), (not listed under unity for some reason) the number format seems to be very specific for the API.

The format seems to require

```
+1 650-555-3434 (not a real number)
```

But the format you provided, might not work.

```
+1xxxxxxxxxx
```